# xAxis tickInterval throwing error in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Problem**

If the xAxis.tickInterval is set to anything, when activating the FullScreen view this error is thrown:

```
TypeError: t.toPrecision is not a function

highcharts-complete.min.js:1:8079
```

**Details**

- The data series is sequential years, written as text (2011, 2012, 2013, etc).
- The data source is an HTML table on the page.
- This does not happen if the xAxis.tickInterval is left to default
- This does not happen with xAxis.tickInterval if the xAxis.type = "dateTime" when using a series containing dates
- This does not happen at all with yAxis.tickInterval

Comment: hi there, welcome, first add a jsfiddle example if you need some help, we need see our patient

Answer (score 0):

In the process of trying to build a simplified version of the code in question so I could post it to JSFiddle, I managed to solve my own problem, though it does raise a question.

I was using Javascript to extract chart options from data-attributes set on the table being used as the data source. Which all worked just fine, except for the xAxis.tickInterval.

Turns out, it was trying to parse the value as a precision when it needed an integer. The solution was to use parseInt around the call to the table.dataset.

Interestingly, this error does not occur on the yAxis.tickInterval despite both being set by data-attributes and using the same code to programmatically build out the chart options JSON.

Solved, but curious as to why it fails with xAxis and succeeds with yAxis.

If anyone is curious about it, the line in question is 180, and here's the JSFiddle link:

[Chart xAxis.tickInterval](https://jsfiddle.net/kbrownridge/nLuyod6a/4/)

```
 rdOptions.xAxis['tickInterval'] = parseInt(table.dataset.xAxisTickInterval);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why this error occurs and why you need to use parsInt is that your **table.dataset.xAxisTickInterval** is a string, not number, but tickInterval must be a number as you can find in the documentation: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval

Why it is work for yAxis? Accidentally ;) just like true or false will work, because JavaScript will get it as 0 or 1.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gpw0a4qr/

```
xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1
  },

yAxis: {
    tickInterval: true
  },
```

And why this error occurs in your case only in fullscreen mode? Because it seems that tickInterval was caluclated to 1 by default and this update which you do later didn't change it(didn't trigger the redraw, but change the value from 1 to '1' in options). But fullscreen mode triggers chart redraw and after your update tickInterval was set to '1', which is incorrect.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ctja0db9/